# How to create custom permission for specific fields in model?

Tags: python, django

I have created a model and I want to create an user group that has the permission of edit only one field of this model.

For example if I have `Car` model with some fields (for example `model`, `brand`, `registration`) and one basic user, I want that the user is able to change only **registration** field.

It is possible to do that?

Comment: Could you add some code to show you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        # your custom permissions
        permissions = (
            ('model_can_edit_title', _('Can Edit Title')),
        )
```

do makemigration and migrate.

admin.py:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    # you can check user type. and make decision
    if 'app.model_can_edit_title' in request.user.user.get_all_permissions():
        # user can update all fields
        return []
    # user can't update title field, title will be read only.
    return ['title',]
```

you can use

```
def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
```

method also.